# How to add new line on JS append html

Tags: javascript

I have some node list, and I am trying to get some values from this list.
It works fine but I can't append the values in new lines and everything rendered together.

```
    <div class="newinsert"></div>

  <script>
    const indiv = document.querySelector('.newinsert')
    const flist = document.querySelectorAll('someclass')
    const listClean = [...flist]
    
    console.log(listClean);
    listClean.forEach(list=> {
      const html = `${list.innerHTML} `
      indiv.append(html)
    })
  </script>
```

I tried adding `<br>` on html var but it just prints `<br>` with ""

\n doesn't work too

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: ok fixed it by

**`indiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',` ${html} < br >`)`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) function receive string  or HTMLNode element ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append))

but if your purpose is just to learn,you can simply replace  InnerHtml content with your Html;
or concatenate it to the current content;

```js
    const indiv = document.querySelector('.newinsert')
    const flist = document.querySelectorAll('someclass')
    const listClean = [...flist]
    
    console.log(listClean);
    listClean.forEach(list=> {
      const html = `${list.innerHTML}<br> `
      indiv.innerHTML = html
      //or 
      indiv.innerHTML =  indiv.innerHTML+html // if you effectly want to append conent to current dev content 

    })
```

```html
    <div class="newinsert"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the append function in JS to simplify your code.

Try this snippet:

```js
// JS function to copy elements
const indiv = document.querySelector('.newinsert')
const flist = document.querySelectorAll('.someclass')

// Copy all elements with append
flist.forEach(list=> {
    indiv.appendChild(list.cloneNode(true))
    // if you want force a new line:
    // indiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
})
```

```css
.someclass { color: #00F; }
.someotherclass { color: #F00; }
```

```html
<h3>Elements with someclass and someotherclass</h3>
<div class='someclass'>element 1</div>
<p class='someclass'><b>element 2</b></p>
<div class='someotherclass'><small>element 3 [NOT TO COPY]</small></div>
<button class='someclass'><big>element 4</big></button>

<h3>Copied Elements</h3>
<div class='newinsert'></div>
```